# Does MSTest V2 support C++/CLI unit test projects?

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, mstest

In Visual Studio 2017 you can create a new Visual C++ "Managed Test Project" from the project templates creating a unit test project written in C++/CLI allowing for interoperability between .Net & native C++.  The template creates an original MSTest V1 project with a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.

However I want to upgrade this unit test project to MSTest V2, taking advantage of new features.

Removing the QualityTools reference and adding references to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework & Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions and then building yields the following warnings:

> \helloworld2017\helloworld\unittestcplusplusmgd\unittest.cpp(12):
>   warning C4691: 'System::Attribute': type referenced was expected in
>   unreferenced assembly 'System.Runtime', type defined in current
>   translation unit used instead
>   \helloworld2017\helloworld\unittestcplusplusmgd\unittest.cpp(12):
>   note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type
>   'Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting::TestClassAttribute '
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Is it expected MSTest V2 works with C++/CLI unit test projects?  And if so are there templates providing an example to create a basic MSTest V2 C++/CLI unit test project which builds correctly without warnings?

Comment: .NETCore never had good C++/CLI support.  Might change some day now that v3 implements the missing hosting feature with ijwhost.dll.  Future music.

Comment: Allow me to summarize: MSTest V2 is built upon .Net Core, and .Net Core didn't add C++/CLI support until version 3.x.  So if I wait a bit to grab a latest version of MSTest V2 via NuGet that is built on .Net Core 3.x then I may be able to create C++/CLI test projects.